# How do I replace a word in a string in python?

Tags: python, text

Let us say I have a string

```
c = "a string is like this and roberta a a thanks"
```

I want the output to be as

```
' string is like this and roberta   thanks"
```

This is what I am trying

```
c.replace('a', ' ')

' string is like this  nd robert       thnks'
```

But this replaces each 'a' in the string

So I tried this

```
c.replace(' a ', ' ') 

'a string is like this and roberta      thanks'
```

But this leaves out 'a' in the starting of the string.

How do i do this?

Comment: There are several ways - use regular expressions, use `str.split`, ...

Comment: I am not familiar to regular expressions. An example would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Is searching so hard? Try: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Comment: also helpful for learning: http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself figured it out.

```
c = "a string is like this and roberta a a thanks"

import re

re.sub('\\ba\\b', ' ', c)

'  string is like this and roberta     thanks'
```

Here you go myself! Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a job for `re` :

```
import re
while re.subn('(\s+a\s+|^a\s+)',' ',txt)[1]!=0:
    txt=re.subn('(\s+a\s+|^a\s+)',' ',txt)[0]
```